# How to determine upper and lower boundaries for HSL color detection ?

Tags: python, opencv, color-detection

When I use any color space converter it only gives me single values for H,S and L but how to determine the range boundaries from this, also the converters gives me S & L values in % not value in the range from 0-255. 
I need to use this color selection in a python pipeline.
Any help ?

Comment: Not sure what your question really is, but use Google to find an *”HSL Colourwheel”* and pass that through a converter and check the ranges you get out as results to find the limits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize % values. Opencv takes 0-180 for H baundary and 0-255 for S and L values. You can also compute by hand. For example: 100% =255 and 50%=127.